# Stack implementation that a class contains an object of the same class

Tags: c#

I've read a code of Stack implementation in C#.

The code is working but I don't understand whether it is illegal (I am sure it is legal as I can compile it) to have a object of a class inside the same class. The code is as follows.

```
public class Stack{

    Entry top;

    public void Push(object data){
        top = new Entry(top, data);    
    }

    public object Pop(){
        if(top==null) throw new InvalidOperationException();    

        object result = top.data;   
        top = top.next;  

        return result;   
    }

    class Entry{

        public Entry next;//?
        public object data;

        public Entry(Entry next, object data){
            this.next = next;
            this.data = data;
        }

    }
}
```

The code is compiled and running ok.

I am confused that inside of the Entry class, it has a field `next` of Entry class.

Furthermore, when Stack is calling Push method, it calls the Entry constructor, which set `this.next` to `next`, but I don't understand how this works, `this.next` will point to object `next`, but where and how the object "next" being created.

I am very appreciated if someone could help me to understand the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `next` stores a reference to another object of `Entry`, *or a null reference*. Note that `next` *could be null*!

Your confusion probably comes from the misconception that to create an `Entry`, you must need an instance of `Entry` first, which seems quite circular on first sight. However, note that you could pass `null` as the first parameter:

```
Entry entry1 = new Entry(null, someObject);
```

Essentially, `Entry` represents a node in a linked list, which in turn is used to implement the stack:

```
A ---> B ---> C
```

The `next` of `A` is `B`. `next` of `B` is `C`. What's the `next` of `C`? It's `null`!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It all makes sense now.

Comment: I felt if in the code, add a constructor for Stack and point top to null, it makes this clear. Fro example, public Stack(){ top = null;}. or it is absolutely unnecessary?

Comment: @yche That is unnecessary, because a parameterless constructor will be automatically generated by the compiler if no constructors are declared. All the fields are set the default values of their types. For `Entry` (and all other reference types), the default value is null.

Comment: thanks again for your comments. I sort of think that the default reference types will be set as null but I didn't know that the compiler actually generate a constructor for you.

Comment: While you can *think* of it as declaring a parameterless constructor for you automatically, this will only happen if you have no constructors at all in the class. If you declare them yourself, as you have, instead what will happen is that invisible initialization code will be added to the top of the constructor(s). This will happen if you have non-default assignments for your fields. Default assignments, like null-references, the number 0, etc. is handled by the fact that the memory allocated to the object is initialized to all zeroes before the constructors execute.

Comment: You can see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpeqpwBZKBZACgEpGzVgF9hLcW2p5KAFTixJTEq1VScBAAyUAahAwBXOJQC8lAETzY5gNylJqinIUwBjSmJVqWTq67QAdjCUAG76RoIglDAAFmhQbgweDqy+LrzAAPaZGKHhcIJJnqqeIkA==) for an example, look at the IL for .ctor() and .ctor(bool 'value'), both will assign a string instance to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Work flow like that

1. Push() , `top = new Entry(top, data);` (A) , `top.next` <--- null
2. Push() , `top = new Entry(top, data);` (B) , `top.next` <--- (A)
3. Push() , `top = new Entry(top, data);` (C), `top.next` <--- (B)
4. Pop() , return (C) , top = (B);
5. Pop() , return (B) , top = (A);
6. Pop() , return (A) , top = null ;
7. Pop() , throw `InvalidOperationException` because `top == null` now.

   And your first question (where and how the object "next" being created)

First push is SPECIALY, it's next is null , But it's ok , because when pop() , It have null check.

Comment: Thank you for your visualized answer.